# How to have 3 horizontal lines with even spacing?

Tags: microsoft-word, line-spacing

If you type `---` in Word and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it will be converted to a horizontal line. However, if you do it 3 times, then the spacing between them isn't even.

[image]

Is there a way to make it even? One goaround way is to create a 4×1 table and draw only the top border. However I don't want to use this since it has more space with the above text than the beneath text. (Usually the above text is to introduce what one should do with the lines, while the beneath text moves on to a different topic. So the space with the above text should be less than with the beneath one.)

[image]

Comment: Which Office version?

Comment: It should be Office 2019, but checking the info in File -> Account it says Office 16

Comment: It's the same. I don't get the same results, for me in Office 365, the distance between lines 2-3 is two pixels less than lines 1-2. It might be related to the document properties at this point. If you post a small document, I could have a look.

Answer (score 2):

1. Select the lines.
2. Go to the Design tab.
3. Click on Paragraph Spacing.
4. Select No Paragraph Space.

[image]

Comment: is there a way to make it only apply to the lines, not other paragraphs? Selecting the lines doesn't seem to work

Comment: Even if you don't select the line, put the cursor between lines 2 and 3, then select No Paragraph Space.

Comment: It still affects other paragraphs for me